# ‘graphresult’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c, bgi

I'm trying to run a `graphics` program on my `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` system to print the `error code` for failed graphics operation. My code is

```
    #include <graphics.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
       int gd, gm, errorcode;

       initgraph(&gd, &gm, NULL);

       errorcode = graphresult();

       if(errorcode != grOk)
       {
          printf("Graphics error: %s\n", grapherrormsg(errorcode));
          printf("Press any key to exit.");
          getch();
          exit(1);
       }

       getch();
       closegraph();
       return 0;
    }
```

But when I run it I get the following error :

```
g++ -o mygraphics mygraphics.c -lgraph
mygraphics.c: In function ‘int main()’:
mygraphics.c:10:20: error: ‘graphresult’ was not declared in this scope
        errorcode = graphresult();
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
mygraphics.c:12:24: error: ‘grOk’ was not declared in this scope
        if(errorcode != grOk)
                        ^~~~
mygraphics.c:12:24: note: suggested alternative: ‘brk’
        if(errorcode != grOk)
                        ^~~~
                        brk
mygraphics.c:14:42: error: ‘grapherrormsg’ was not declared in this scope
           printf("Graphics error: %s\n", grapherrormsg(errorcode));
```

I searched all over the internet but not able to find a promising solution. Can someone help me out please. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `graphics.h` is horribly outdated, you should replace it with a more modern library (e.g. SDL2).

Comment: Are you sure that the `<graphics.h>` header file you include is one that includes the `graphresult` function? The [BGI (Borland Graphics Interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Graphics_Interface) have never been standardized or otherwise widely available or used (beyond absolute beginners who don't know anything else) since the DOS days, so maybe the implementation you found doesn't have all functions of BGI implemented?

Comment: is that C or C++?

Comment: Actually graphics is in my school syllabus so I have to study it.But can you tell me some alternative of `graphresult()` function. It will be a great help

Comment: @ OznOg You can assume in it whatever you want. It just implements basic `graphics.h` functions, not language specific.

Comment: If it's a requirement from your school then they should have provided the library and its header files, which should contain all functions they teach you. If the school have told you to use `graphresult` but supplied a library whose header file doesn't declare it, then you need to bring it up with your school.

Comment: @RudreshDixit If you have to use it, the easiest option is to run Turbo C++ in the Dosbox.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I got it. I will try your approach.